# When using Groovy indy together with Intellij non Indy version is also on classpath

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-14

I have a Groovy-indy project running in Intellij 13 with Gradle.

```
 dependencies {
 compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7:indy'
 ...
```

The problem is that I have two dependencies in my libraries. The indy version and the normal version.

[image]

How can I get rid of the non indy version.

Just removing it is not an option as it is back after restart or Gradle refresh or any other occasion.

**Update Intellij 14:**
Now with intellij 14 there is a different Problem:

```
Error:Groovyc: Cannot use invokedynamic, indy module was excluded from this build.
```

the dependency is the same.

Comment: Have you tried looking using dependency insight to see if it is coming in transitively? gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency groovy --configuration compile

Comment: @DylanBijnagte I did the result is:   
`org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7    
\--- compile
`   
Indy is a classifier of `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7`

Comment: created a ticket for intellij it seem there are already some similar issues https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126878

Answer (score 0):

So if you right-click your project in the Project pane (where you drill-down into folders and such), I had a context-menu option called "Add Framework Support", which allowed me to add Groovy (asked for a Groovy home and added it as a Global Library).

After that, go to Project Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Groovy Compiler. There you should see a checkbox called "Invoke dynamic support". I unchecked that and that removed this error for me.

If you actually ARE trying to use dynamic support, then unfortunately not sure what the deal is.

[Project settings picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyDZO.png)